# Generic type name and value

Tags: generics, types, delphi-xe2

I have a Generic factory. I want to get the type name and its value as a string, eg:

An enumeration `TTV` with a value of `Samsung` would return `'TTV.Samsung'`.

A string with a value of `'stackoverflow'` would return `'string.stackoverflow'`.

An integer with a value of `10` would return `'integer.10'`.

A `TValue` made from `TTV.Samsung` (eg `TValue.From(TTV.Samsung)`) would return `'TTV.Samsung'`.

Here is my function declaration:

```
function TGenericFactory<TKey>.GetTypeString(Key: TKey): string;
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: Getting the name of a type is routine. Do you know anything at all about rtti? Why not start by learning about rtti? If you did even the most basic research you'd know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TValue` has a `ToString()` method that handles the bulk of this work for you, so you can have your function create a temp `TValue` from any input value and then use `TValue.ToString()` to convert the value to a string regardless of what type it actually is.  You can use RTTI to get the input value's type name.  In the case where the input value is a `TValue`, you can use the RTTI of the type that the `TValue` is holding.

```
uses
  System.Rtti;

type
  TGenericFactory<TKey> = class
  public
    class function GetTypeString(Key: TKey): string;
  end;

function TValueToString(const V: TValue): string; inline;
begin
  Result := String(V.TypeInfo.Name) + '.' + V.ToString;
end;

class function TGenericFactory<TKey>.GetTypeString(Key: TKey): string;
type
  PTValue = ^TValue;
begin
  if TypeInfo(TKey) = TypeInfo(TValue) then
    Result := TValueToString(PTValue(@Key)^)
  else
    Result := TValueToString(TValue.From<TKey>(Key));
end;
```

Here are the results:

```
type
  TTV = (Nokia, Samsung, Motorola);

var
  S: String;
begin
  S := TGenericFactory<TTV>.GetTypeString(TTV.Samsung);
  // returns 'TTV.Samsung'

  S := TGenericFactory<String>.GetTypeString('stackoverflow');
  // returns 'string.stackoverflow'

  S := TGenericFactory<Integer>.GetTypeString(10);
  // returns 'Integer.stackoverflow'

  S := TGenericFactory<TValue>.GetTypeString(TValue.From(TTV.Samsung));
  // returns 'TTV.Samsung'
end.
```